# Optimizing very slow PostgreSQL LEFT JOIN between two large tables

Tags: postgresql, left-join, postgresql-performance

For this case I have two tables in my database.  One storing transactions entered by a user and another storing accounts that each transaction can be assigned to.  Accounts have the ability to be marked as inactive and users also have the ability to enter transactions that aren't assigned to an account.

I have a query to grab the first 400 transactions a user has entered where the account is active or the user didn't assign the transaction to an account.

The query looks like this:

```sql
select t.*
from transactions_20000 as t 
left join accounts as a 
    on t.account_id = a.id 
where t.user_id = 1 
    and (a.status=1 or t.account_id=0) 
order by t.date desc, t.transaction_type asc, t.id desc 
limit 400 offset 0;
```

When I run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query, I get the following result: https://explain.depesz.com/s/YM2v The problem seems to be in step #5 where it takes over a second and a half to process that part of the query.  While a total run time of 1.6 seconds doesn't seem like a lot, it really starts to add up when there are thousands of users hitting that query hourly when they load the app.  Obviously changing the limit won't really affect anything since that's not where the slow part is.

I'm at a bit of a loss in trying to figure out how to speed this query up.  I know it shouldn't take this long and it's bugging me that I'm probably missing something easy.

The `transactions` table has a 4 million rows in it, only about 10k of which are assigned to the user.  The `accounts` table has about 2 million rows in it.

For reference, here are the two tables:

```
Table "public.accounts"
    Column    |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
--------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id           | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id      | integer                        |           | not null | 
 name         | character varying(250)         |           |          | 
 type_id      | integer                        |           | not null | 
 status       | integer                        |           | not null | 
 currency_id  | integer                        |           |          | 1
 credit_limit | numeric(15,2)                  |           |          | 0
 group_id     | integer                        |           |          | 0
 created_at   | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          | 
 updated_at   | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "accounts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "a_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

```
Table "public.transactions_20000"
       Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                     
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 id                 | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('transactions_20000_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id            | integer                     |           | not null | 
 date               | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 amount             | numeric(15,2)               |           | not null | 
 transaction_type   | integer                     |           | not null | 0
 description        | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 account_id         | integer                     |           |          | 0
 category_id        | integer                     |           |          | 0
 jive               | integer                     |           |          | 0
 specialstatus      | character varying(50)       |           |          | 
 parent             | integer                     |           |          | 0
 ccparent           | integer                     |           |          | 0
 related_transfer   | character varying(50)       |           | not null | 0
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 check_num          | character varying(32)       |           |          | 
 payee              | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 memo               | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 additional_user_id | integer                     |           |          | 0
 initial_balance    | boolean                     |           |          | 
 jived_date         | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 attachment         | character varying(100)      |           |          | 
 add_source         | character(25)               |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "transactions_20000_unique_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "transactions_20000_user_ccparent_idx" btree (user_id, ccparent) WHERE ccparent > 0
    "transactions_20000_user_date_idx" btree (user_id, date)
    "transactions_20000_user_id_key" btree (user_id)
```

Does anyone see anything obvious that's causing this query to take so long?

Comment: You should turn track_io_timing on and then do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this?

Comment: jjanes, it's version 11.8.  The database currently has 15GB of ram and 512GB storage capacity.  It's the Standard-3 plan on Heroku (https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).  I'll also look into the track_io_timing and see what extra info that gives me.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is spending most of the time reading data from disk for the transactions table, jumping to different parts of the table.  One way to improve that (other than getting faster disks, or more RAM so that the data is cached) would be to CLUSTER the table on the index transactions_20000_user_date_idx, or one of the other indexes which lead with user_id.  That would group all the data for the same user_id together on disk.  The problem is that a clustered table won't stay clustered for future INSERTs or UPDATEs.

Another option is to create an index on

```
create index on transactions_20000 (user_id,date, transaction_type desc, id );
```

Or

```
create index on transactions_20000 (user_id,date desc, transaction_type, id desc);
```

With either of those indexes, it could collect the rows already in the order it needs them, and stop early once it has obtained 400 which meet the conditions.  Rather than collecting all 3,274 rows, then sorting them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually retrieve anything from `accounts` I would rewrite the query as:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   transactions_20000 t 
WHERE  t.user_id = 1 
AND   (t.account_id = 0 OR
       EXISTS (SELECT FROM accounts a WHERE a.id = t.account_id AND a.status = 1))
ORDER  BY t.date DESC, t.transaction_type, t.id DESC
LIMIT  400;
```

That probably doesn't change much yet, though.

#### Index

A multicolumn index with columns in *this* order should help performance:

```
CREATE INDEX transactions_20000_special_idx ON transactions_20000
(user_id, date DESC, transaction_type, id DESC, account_id);
```

It delivers rows per `user_id` readily sorted and also covers the `account_id` we need to join to `accounts`. Should get rid of the expensive `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan`  in your query plan.

(Not sure if adding `account_id` is an improvement.)

**If** most accounts are not active (`status <> 1`), this partial index (consequently small) should help some more:

```
CREATE INDEX accounts_special_idx ON accounts (id)
WHERE status = 1;
```